# Extend methods in WCF OData Service

Tags: entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I created WCF OData service referring my project DAL which is based on EF6.
Here, I'm referring to an extended class to my DataContext, called MyDbContext.

```
namespace PScope.DAL
{

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    PScopeDB db = new PScopeDB();

    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=PScopeDB")   
    {
    }

     public IQueryable<Task> TaskList
    {
        get
        {
            return db.Tasks;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this class, I'm trying to create a new method, which will have few joins to return a new entity. And I defined the entity in my DataService class with WebGet method.

```
namespace PrimariusScope.DataService
{

[JSONPSupportBehavior]
public class DataService : EntityFrameworkDataService<DAL.MyDbContext>, IServiceProvider
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;

    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == typeof(IDataServiceStreamProvider))
        {
            // Return the stream provider to the data service.
            return new ImageStreamProvider();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Define a query interceptor for the Resources entity set.
    [QueryInterceptor("Resources")]
    public Expression<Func<DAL.Resource, bool>> OnQueryResources()
    {
        return o => o.Active == true;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public IQueryable<DAL.Task> TaskList()
    {
        DAL.MyDbContext entities = new DAL.MyDbContext();
        return entities.TaskList;
    }
}
}
```

But when I run my service, the TaskList method is not exposed. `http://localhost:12034/DataService.svc/TaskList` returns Not Found.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing following declaration :

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) {
    ...
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("TaskList", ServiceOperationRights.All);
    ...
}
```